# Flutter - The app directory path from IOS change but i save it in the database

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a bit confused about the path between Android and IOS. For the moment my application I have worked on Android, I have created the following :

```dart
      late Directory appDir;

      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      } else {
        appDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
      }

      String itemDirPath = "";

      if (someVariableBoolean) {
        itemDirPath = "${appDir.path}/file";
      } else {
        itemDirPath = "${appDir.path}-$itemId";
      }

      final Directory newDir = Directory(itemDirPath);

      if (newDir.existsSync()) {
        return newDir;
      } else {
        final Directory dir = await newDir.create(recursive: true);
        return dir;
      }
```

I create a new directory because in my app I will have different types of files. I return the directory and when I create a new File(), I take the path of the directory and I save that path in the database...

Already from the UI, in a Widget Image I show the saved path, the problem is that in IOS the id of the path directory changes every time I update it or redebug the app... I would not know how to manage here, I have seen some comments of just calling the dir.path but you have to save it in the database. Any suggestions?